# math problem probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and finite variance. Prove that:

$$T_n= \binom{n}{2}^{-1} \sum_{1\leq i< j\leq n} {X_{i}X_{j}} \overset{P}{\rightarrow} \mu ^2 \text{ when } n \rightarrow \infty. $$

Indication: Prove the quadratic mean convergence.

I try to do this:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }E[(T_{n} - \mu ^2)^2] = 0?$$

I have calculated the mean of $T_{n}$ and I think $E(T_{n})=\mu^2$ so,

$$E[(T_{n} - \mu ^2)^2]=E(T_{n}^2)-E(T_{n})^2 = \mu^4-(\mu^2)^2=0. $$

The problem is that I don't use the fact $n\rightarrow \infty $.

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: $E(T_n^2) \ne \mu^4$

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter points out, $E(T_n^2)$ isn't $\mu^4$ exactly, but asymptotically, and that's where you use $n \to \infty$. Specifically, counting terms I get 
$E(\Sigma_{i<j}X_iX_j)={n\choose 2}{n-2\choose 2}E(X_1)E(X_2)E(X_3)E(X_4)+O(n^3)$, then $E(T_n)={n\choose 2}{n-2\choose 2}{n\choose 2}^{-2}\mu^4+O(1/n)\to \mu^4$. Then as you suggest the result follows form Chebyshev's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1,X_2$ are iid, then $$Var(X_1 X_2)=E(X_1^2 X_2^2)-E(X_1X_2)^2=(\sigma^2+\mu^2)^2-\mu^4=\sigma^4+2\sigma^2\mu^2$$

Hence $$Var(T_n)=\binom{n}{2}^{-1} Var(X_1 X_2)=\frac{\sigma^4+2\sigma^2\mu^2}{n (n-1)/2}\to 0$$

Also $E[T_n]= \mu^2$.  Hence we have convergence in quadratic mean, which implies convergence in probability.

Comment: But why you don't consider $Cov(X_{i}X_{j},X_{i}X_{j+1})$? Thanks

Comment: Why should I? I'm not computing $E(T_n^2)$. My first formula is general. Then I compute $Var(T_n)$ by using $Var(a[ X+Y+Z])=a^2 [Var(X)+Var(Y)+Var(Z)]$

Comment: You can use this formula if X, Y, Z are independent but in my problem $X_{1}X_{2}$ and $X_{2}X_{3}$ for example, I think are not independent...